# display and/or use awk FILENAME on empty files

Tags: awk

Is there a way to print filename of "empty" file in a awk.

trying to reply to another awk question that need peer of file (1 file + same filename + extension) i create several file with touch (so empty one).
Let's say:

```
file1.raw
file1.raw.ext
file2.raw
file2.raw.ext
```

I than use the code

```
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME;print FILENAME".ext"};#some other action on line' file*.raw
```

result is empty (right, FNR is never 1). how can a  print files name when they are treated ? is there a `FNR==0` or `BEGINF` ? I can use argument list and compare but this will be treated asynchronously (BEGIN or END of FNR==1 of a file having at least 1 line)

```
expected result
file1.raw
(some action result here if file1.raw was not empty)
file1.raw.ext
file2.raw
(some action result here if file2.raw was not empty)
file2.raw.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

idk why some moderator (@ChrisF) deleted this first time around but this IS the correct answer to this question so let's try again and if that person has a question or comment then perhaps they can post it like a reasonable person would instead of erroneously deleting the correct answer:

with GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME}1' *
```

with other awks (untested):

```
awk '
FNR==1 {
    for (++ARGIND;ARGV[ARGIND]!=FILENAME;ARGIND++) {
        print ARGV[ARGIND]
    }
    print FILENAME
}
{ print }
END {
    for (++ARGIND;ARGIND in ARGV;ARGIND++) {
        print ARGV[ARGIND]
    }
}' *
```

Comment: @ChrisF the answer I posted and which you so rudely and incorrectly deleted is THE correct, precise answer to this specific question so I've posted it again. If you think the question is a duplicate then delete that, but what is the point of leaving the question but deleting the answer to it? Let me know if you have any questions.